# Position child element directly under and justified right to the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am creating a dropdown menu component using React. I would like to know the CSS required to position the menu element directly under the ".menu-trigger" button, with its right border aligned to its parent's (".menu-container"), right border. I would like this CSS to be able to position a menu element of any reasonable size like this.

I believe I want to position the ".menu" component absolutely, relative to the parent, ".menu-container", element.

Below is a stripped down version of html and css:

```
    <body>
        <div className="menu-container">
            <button className="menu-trigger">
                <span>Drop Down Menu</span>
            </button>
            <nav className="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>

    <style>

        .menu ul {
          list-style: none;
        }

        .menu-container {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .menu {
          position: absolute;
          top: 100%;
        }

    </style>
```

**** Edit ****

Solved using flexbox solution:

```
    .menu-container {
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }
```

Comment: And if you haven't: start using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) CSS, or if you need absolutely the most precise possible layout control, look into using [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) - but that one's crazy complex and rarely the right choice.

Comment: To be correct, your title should read "Position element directly under prior sibling and right-aligned to the parent element".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to right-align using flexbox:

```css
.menu-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;  /* flexbox container */
  flex-direction: column;  /* children in columns */
  align-items: flex-end; /* children right-aligned */
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.menu-trigger {}

.menu {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 .5rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h4>Right-alignment using flexbox</h4>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <button class="menu-trigger">
      <span>Drop Down Menu</span>
    </button>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```